# Stencil Creating `.stencil` folder instead of `components` inside `dist/types` directory

Tags: web-component, stenciljs, stencil-component, stencil-compiler

Stencil Creating `.stencil` folder  instead of `components`  inside `dist/types` directory

I have tried with version 2.1.2 / 2.4.0/ 2.5.0

In all the cases, it is creating .stencil directory which contains all the components.

In other team mates system, it is creating `components` despite of having the same configuration.

Can anyone here help me here, why different folders are getting create on different system.

Due to this, my interface files are not able to read as it is pointing to component directory but stencil creating `.stencil`